# Overwrite parent model attribute from child model

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model parent

```
class ModelParent(PolymorphicModel):

    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    .......
```

and the model child

```
class ModelChild(ModelParent)

     company = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
     ...........
```

how can I make the model child **company** attribute overwrite the parent **company** model attribute without making the **abstract** parent model

Comment: Well you have to understand it like this: Django models such models as two tables: a `parent` table (with the company), and a `child` table (which then should have a `company as well?). So It is probably better to construct validators for it (at the Django level) here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [not possible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted) without an abstract parent model, unfortunately.

> ### Field name “hiding” is not permitted
>
> In normal Python class inheritance, it is permissible for a child class to override any attribute from the parent class. In Django, this isn’t usually permitted for model fields. If a non-abstract model base class has a field called author, you can’t create another model field or define an attribute called author in any class that inherits from that base class.
>
> This restriction doesn’t apply to model fields inherited from an abstract model. Such fields may be overridden with another field or value, or be removed by setting field_name = None.

A recommendation instead would be to simply create a property or rename the child model's field. Another thing you could do is remove the parent model's "company" field and move it to all of the children models instead.

```
class ModelChild(ModelParent)

 child_company = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
 ...........
```